# Using async result (array.filter)

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

So I have an array where I need to filter it from `undefined` values and then use it (please see the following example!) so since filter method is async there is no guarantee that results array is filtered where I'm logging it!

```
//Here I need to filter the results from undefined!
results = results.filter(function (item) {
    return item !== undefined;
});
//But since the filter method is async, it is not guaranteed that results is filtered here yet!
console.log(results)
```

Comment: Use [async.filter()](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async#filter).

Comment: The standard [`.filter()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) does work synchronously. Unless something within the `function` provided to it is asynchronous, the results will be available for the next line of code.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski So you mean my `results.filter` in my code runs `synchronously` although I have a callback function in it?

Comment: @user3421904 Yes. Just because a method takes a function does not make it asynchronous. If that `filter()` method is the standard `Array.prototype.filter` method it will be called synchronously for each element in the array.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski This may be useful in future for other people, please feel free to answer the question and I mark it as solved